# Desenvolvendo um BOT para enquetes com plugin Polldaddy do wordpress

Tags: python

Tentei seguir: https://github.com/dado3212/PollDaddyHack

```
import requests

dados ={"poll_id" : "9484127",
"answer_id" :"43276282",
"number_of_votes" : "1000"}



url = "https://polldaddy.com/poll/9484127/"

#while True:
requests.post(url, data=dados)
```

Mas continua não votando e nem dá erros!

Comment: Testei https://github.com/dado3212/PollDaddyHack . E já não funciona tanto em python3 como o 2 . Mas para testar seria copiar isso para um ficheiro e mudar os ultimos parametros do ficheiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que a utilização correta desse módulo será:

```
from vote import vote

poll_id = 9484127
answer_id = 43276282
number_of_votes = 1000

vote(poll_id, answer_id, number_of_votes)
```

Comment: Existe a biblioteca vote em python?

Comment: @EdMail Não existe por defeito mas se carregares a que tu indicaste passa a existir. Como não foi declarada no PyPI, terás de carregar e colocar manualmente o ficheiro "vote.py" na mesma diretoria que tens o teu script.

Comment: Não entendi: "vote.py será o meu programa?

Comment: Sou bem iniciante. Desculpe a ignorância: 
 
Não entendi: "vote.py será o meu programa?

Comment: @EdMail vote.py é o ficheiro do módulo que indicaste que está alojada no github (https://github.com/dado3212/PollDaddyHack)

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 770
    InsecureRequestWarning)
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. É possível corrigir? Obrigado!

Comment: funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Só gostaria de saber como retirar o warning acima!

Comment: @EdS Para remover os aviso podes executar o script da seguinte forma: python -W ignore script.py

Comment: obrigado. Mas como "adding certificate verification is strongly advised" para resolver o warning sem ignorá-lo? É possível?

Comment: @EdS O aviso vem do próprio módulo, terias de editar o próprio ficheiro "vote.py", creio.